# How can I stop ListView from catching and consuming keys pressed (before and instead of the parent activity)?

Tags: android, events, listview

A ListView catches hard keyboard keys (namely arrows up and down) events before the parent Activity does. How to stop it? A parent activity has an elaborated way of work with commands, common for the all activities in the application.  And I needn't default selection movement of the ListView.

**What was done already**:
(After the search about the similar problems.)

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

are set to the ListView xml.

```
lvShows.setEnabled(false);
lvShows.setOnKeyListener(null);
```

are set at the onStart()

Instead of the last line I have tried

```
lvShows.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

});
```

The adapter is set after all these lines. After it no action is done to the list before the first key pressing is done.

All measures against the ListView caused only that it looks a bit pale (after disabling), but it is still sound and healthy enough to catch and consume the every key event that comes.

It catches key events before the parent Activity, moves the item selection itself and never passes the events to the Activity.

---

Android version 2.3.3.